# Code works differently in Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have ported a consoleApp to a Docker container with the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`. Now I noticed that the code inside the container behaves differently. Outside the container, an exception is generated when the connection is lost but Not inside the container! What can be the reason?

Many thanks for your help.

```
        public static async Task FtpUploadAsync(string hostname, string username, string password, string[] uploadfiles)
    {
        try
        {
            var token = new CancellationToken();
            using (AsyncFtpClient client = new AsyncFtpClient())
            {
                client.Host = hostname;
                client.Port = 21;
                client.Credentials.UserName = username;
                client.Credentials.Password = password;
                client.Config.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.None;
                client.Config.InternetProtocolVersions = FtpIpVersion.IPv4;
                client.Config.ValidateAnyCertificate = true;
                client.Config.ConnectTimeout = 15000;
                await client.AutoConnect(token);

                Console.WriteLine("Connectetd!");

                foreach (var varFilePath in uploadfiles)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploading File: " + varFilePath.GetFtpFileName());
                    await client.UploadFile(varFilePath, "/" + varFilePath.GetFtpFileName(), FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite, true, token: token);
                    File.Delete(varFilePath);
                    WriteLogFile.WriteLog("File Uploaded", varFilePath.GetFtpFileName());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogFile.WriteLog("catch", "Ftp-Uploader " + ex);
            Console.WriteLine("Ftp-Uploader " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Hello, how do I include the code to write a debug log! Unfortunately I can't get it! Sorry....

```
using FluentFTP;          // from NuGet package FluentFTP
using FluentFTP.Logging;  // from NuGet package FluentFTP.Logging

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
.WriteTo.File("logs/Net6Tester.txt", rollingInterval: 
RollingInterval.Day)
.CreateLogger();

client.Logger = new FtpLogAdapter(logger);
```

here are the logs! when i run the coed on a windows system then it disposes after a disconnection.
If I run it in the container, then it immediately wants to continue with the next file in the array!!

```
Log -- Windows System
######################
# AutoConnect()

# AutoDetect(True, False)

# Connect(False)
Status:   FluentFTP 44.0.1.0
Status:   Connecting to IP #1= ***:21
Status:   Waiting for a response
Response: 220 Xlight FTP Server 3.9 ready... [738548,429d]
Status:   Detected FTP server: XLight
Command:  AUTH TLS
Status:   Waiting for response to: AUTH TLS
Response: 431 No security resource for TLS/SSL encryption, 
probably there is no selected SSL certificate [370ms]
Command:  USER ***
Status:   Waiting for response to: USER ***
Response: 331 Password required for *** [394ms]
Command:  PASS ***
Status:   Waiting for response to: PASS ***
Response: 230 Login OK [297ms]
Command:  FEAT
Status:   Waiting for response to: FEAT
Response: 211-Features supported
Response: REST STREAM
Response: EPRT
Response: EPSV
Response: SIZE
Response: MDTM
Response: MFMT
Response: AUTH
Response: PBSZ
Response: PROT
Response: MLST type*;size*;modify*;
Response: MLSD
Response: 211 End [72ms]
Status:   Text encoding: 
System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed
Command:  OPTS UTF8 ON
Status:   Waiting for response to: OPTS UTF8 ON
Response: 502 This function is disabled [35ms]
Command:  SYST
Status:   Waiting for response to: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8 [18ms]
Status:   Listing parser set to: Machine
Command:  PWD
Status:   Waiting for response to: PWD
Response: 257 "/" [6ms]
Connectetd!
Uploading File: test-big.opus
[11:18:28 INF] Uploading file test-big.opus

# UploadFile("C:\temp\ftpUpload\test-big.opus", "/test-big.opus", 
Overwrite, True, None)

# FileExists("/test-big.opus")
Command:  SIZE /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: SIZE /test-big.opus
Response: 550 Can't find file "test-big.opus". [70ms]

# DirectoryExists("/")

# OpenWrite("/test-big.opus", Binary)
Command:  TYPE I
Status:   Waiting for response to: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I. [23ms]

# OpenDataStreamAsync("STOR /test-big.opus", 0)

# OpenPassiveDataStreamAsync(PASV, "STOR /test-big.opus", 0)
Command:  PASV
Status:   Waiting for response to: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,178,30,195,196) 
[14ms]
Status:   Connecting to IP #1= ***:50116
Command:  STOR /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: STOR /test-big.opus
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for test- 
big.opus. [8ms]
Status:   Closing/Disposing FtpSocketStream(data connection)
Status:   Attempting upload resume at position 1048576

# OpenAppend("/test-big.opus", Binary)

# GetFileSize("/test-big.opus", -1)
Command:  SIZE /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: SIZE /test-big.opus
Status:   Closing/Disposing FtpSocketStream(data connection)

# Dispose()
Status:   Disposing FtpClient object...
Status:   Closing/Disposing FtpSocketStream(control connection)
Status:   Closing/Disposing FtpSocketStream(control connection)

###############################################################
Log-File Docker Container
#########################

# AutoConnect()
# AutoDetect(True, False)
# Connect(False)
Status:   FluentFTP 44.0.1.0
Status:   Connecting to IP #1= ***:21
Status:   Waiting for a response
Response: 220 Xlight FTP Server 3.9 ready... [738548.43d]
Status:   Detected FTP server: XLight
Command:  AUTH TLS
Status:   Waiting for response to: AUTH TLS
Response: 431 No security resource for TLS/SSL encryption, 
probably there is no selected SSL certificate [390ms]
Command:  USER ***
Status:   Waiting for response to: USER ***
Response: 331 Password required for *** [398ms]
Command:  PASS ***
Status:   Waiting for response to: PASS ***
Response: 230 Login OK [299ms]
Command:  FEAT
Response: 211-Features supported
Response: REST STREAM
Response: EPRT
Response: EPSV
Response: SIZE
Response: MDTM
Response: MFMT
Response: AUTH
Response: PBSZ
Response: PROT
Response: MLST type*;size*;modify*;
Response: MLSD
Response: 211 End [73ms]
Status:   Text encoding: 
System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed
Command:  OPTS UTF8 ON
Status:   Waiting for response to: OPTS UTF8 ON
Response: 502 This function is disabled [16ms]
Command:  SYST
Status:   Waiting for response to: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8 [17ms]
Status:   Listing parser set to: Machine
Command:  PWD
Status:   Waiting for response to: PWD
Response: 257 "/" [6ms]
Connectetd!
Uploading File: test-big.opus
[10:18:36 INF] Uploading file test-big.opus

# UploadFile("/var/lib/ftp-uploader/input/test-big.opus", 
"/test- 
big.opus", Overwrite, True, None)
# FileExists("/test-big.opus")
Command:  SIZE /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: SIZE /test-big.opus
Response: 213 926600 [58ms]

# DeleteFile("/test-big.opus")
Command:  DELE /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: DELE /test-big.opus
Response: 250 Deleted file "test-big.opus". [35ms]


# OpenWrite("/test-big.opus", Binary)
Command:  TYPE I
Status:   Waiting for response to: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I. [14ms]

# OpenDataStreamAsync("STOR /test-big.opus", 0)

# OpenPassiveDataStreamAsync(PASV, "STOR /test-big.opus", 0)
Command:  PASV
Status:   Waiting for response to: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,178,30,195,206) 
[11ms]
Status:   Connecting to IP #1= ***:50126
Command:  STOR /test-big.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: STOR /test-big.opus
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for test- 
big.opus. [1ms]
Status:   Closing/Disposing FtpSocketStream(data connection)
Status:   IOException for file /var/lib/ftp- 
uploader/input/test-big.opus : Unable to write data to the 
transport connection: Broken pipe.
Status:   Failed to upload file.
Uploading File: test-small.opus
[10:18:45 INF] Uploading file test-small.opus

# UploadFile("/var/lib/ftp-uploader/input/test-small.opus", 
"/test-small.opus", Overwrite, True, None)
# FileExists("/test-small.opus")

Command:  SIZE /test-small.opus
Status:   Waiting for response to: SIZE /test-small.opus
```

Comment: Do you mean the exception is never generated, or that it takes a while to be generated?

Comment: The exception is never generated!

Comment: How do you call this method? And how do you detect that exception is thrown?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand!? The method is FluentFTP's FTP client and as soon as Fluent returns an error via await client.UploadFile() try / catch it.

Comment: Do you call `await FtpUploadAsync()`? Or simply `FtpUploadAsync()`? And do you have `await` all the way up the stack?

Comment: i call await FtpUploadAsync()

Comment: Are you calling `await FtpUploadAsync()` from the `Main()` (or whatever entrypoint is in your case)? Or do you have other methods in the middle? I mean await should be used on all the steps from entrypoint to the actual function call.

Comment: i call the Mehtod: await FtpUpload.FtpUploadAsync(data.HostnameFtp, data.UserFtp, password, filePath); thera are no steps between.

Comment: Unrelated: that's not how you should obtain a cancellation token. If you actually want to support cancellation, that is.

Comment: On topic: how do you know there is _no_ exception? Where does StdOut go? Where does your (seemingly custom) logger write to? Is any of the two actually working when running containerized?

Comment: The post goes in the wrong direction!
The question was why an application throws an exception when run under windows and not when run in a docker container! The code is absolutely the same, only the runtime environment is different!

Comment: What happens instead of the exception? Is it hanging there forever? Or does it just silently skip uploading the file? Is AsyncFtpClient your class? If yes, then please provide the code of its `UploadFile`. Also please check what @Fildor suggested about stdout and loggers.

Comment: The code hangs forever at await client.UploadFile( ....). and no exception is thrown! AsyncFtpClient is a class of FluentFTP.

Comment: Which exception do you get outside of the container? What is the callstack?

Comment: Also please configure logging from AsyncFtpClient (see https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/Logging#faq_logfile) and compare the logs on host computer and in container.

Comment: This dispose happens inside client.UploadFile and is normal. You have some issue with `Unable to write data to the transport connection: Broken pipe.` in container. Also the log ends with `Status:   Waiting for response to: SIZE /test-small.opus`. Does it mean that it waits there forever? Anyway, with logs you should be able to troubleshoot it much easier.

Comment: yes, he stays there forever! the broken pipe comes from stopping the FTP service to simulate a break.

Comment: Then something might be broken in FTP connectivity from your container to the server. Passive mode seems to be already there, so it should not be an issue, although you might try setting it explicitly. I've updated the logging configuration in the code sample below to more verbose (timestamps in the output + Verbose level). Could you please collect the logs once again? Also please try uploading with some other client, e.g. Curl: https://everything.curl.dev/ftp/upload.

Answer (score 0):

To configure logging from FTP client you can use the following:

According to [FluentFTP Logging](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/Logging#faq_logfile) page you can setup logging via Serilog. Add the following NuGet packages:

- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog.Sinks.File
- (optionally, to log to console also) Serilog.Sinks.Console

On the start of program configure logging:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.File("logs/Net6Tester.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Then when you create `AsyncFtpClient` configure it to log to Serilog:

```cs
using (AsyncFtpClient client = new AsyncFtpClient())
{
    var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddSerilog())
        .CreateLogger<UploadClient>();
    client.Logger = new FtpLogAdapter(logger);
```

You can also log yourself with something like this:

```cs
Log.Logger.Information("Uploading file {0}", varFilePath.GetFtpFileName());
```

Please first make sure it's logging as expected on your host machine. Then try to get the logs from Docker container.